# ETL - Views or persist tables?

Tags: sql, view, ssis, etl, data-warehouse

When building a Data Warehouse I usually see two main approaches for the ETL-process:

**1. View - View of views - View of views of views - ...**

*Approach one is obviously in the database and has the advantage that you don't have that much redundant data, but could lead to performance issues.*

**2. Stage table (copy of data) - clear table (copy of data) - dwh table (copy of data) - ...**

*Approach two could be done with many tools as stored procedures and jobs or a ETL-tool like SSIS.
The advantage here is that it's easy to understand the process as you can visualise it pretty good. You usually also have a very good overall ETL-performance and many predefined tasks etc.
A problem could be for example, that a change of the process is more complex as persistent tables have to be changed.*

In the real world you usually see a mix of both, especially when many people have worked on the process.
Of course it also depends on the situation (size of tables, how are similar processes designed in this company, how complex is the ETL-process, ...).

I personally prefer to copy tables, keep the ETL-process simple and if possible do everything in the ETL-tool (usually SSIS in my case) which is designed for this purpose.

But what is best practice and why?

Answer (score 0):

views an views of views would not scale with volume of data in DWH. When it comes of dwh i mean we are talking about huge volumes of data. Integration of data from multiple sources is a common usecase for dwh. Stage->tranform-->fact/dim is the one of the most common way how dwh are built to store data. Yes this would change somewhat when we talk about hdfs and other technologies, but views would not be able to give you desired performance in dwh. 
I have seen many systems and all of them have a multi step etl process where you first get data into dwh from sources and then clean/process/conform/transform this data via ETL/others in to your dimensional/other model.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know point-in-time reference data relationships, implemented in a dimensional DW as type-2 or type-3 slowly changing dimensions, you probably won't find this in a source system.

The scale issue mentioned by garpitmzn is not just about data volumes, but also the joins necessary to restructure and denormalise the data for dimensional analysis. Using views (unless materialised) you'd repeat potentially complex joins for every query. Better to do it once at the time the dimension is loaded.